# how to pack circles on the square regularly

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

I want to

circles on the square
[image]

I need to put 64 circles Within the square . How to calculate your radius ? taking into consideration the distance from each other

Comment: Do you want to maximize the radius? In that case, you should check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square and http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/d6.html.

Comment: @Vincent It must have a distance between the circles

Comment: Do you mean that there must be some distance $\eta$ between two consecutive circles?

Comment: If you want it to be regular, like your case, the distance between the centers of two adjacent circles is $\frac{1}{16}$ (I am assuming the distance from a circle to the edge of the square is the same as the one between two adjacent circles)

Comment: If the number is not always 64, look at http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirinsqu/